# openpyxl: crash .xlsx file after save

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, openpyxl

I try to read and write .xlsx file with openpyxl.
I just write text to one cell like below after read existing file.

```
sheet['F50'] = 'Hello'
enter code here
```

The file size of saved file is smaller than before.
And I've get error message when read file with MS-Excel 2013.

```
"We found a problem with some content in 'working.xlsx', Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click yes."
```

After select yes. I've got another message.

```
Repaire to 'working.xlsx'
Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content.
Removed Records: Named range from /xl/workbook.xml part(Workbook)
```

But I can see the 'Hello' on cell 'F50'.
What's wrong with my code.

Comment: I think you should use `sheet['F50'] .value = 'Hello'`. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901558/writing-data-into-excel-sheet-using-openpyxl-isnt-working

Comment: Please post **all** the code you're using.

Comment: I got the same issue now, my code is the simplest: `import openpyxl; book = openpyxl,load_workbook(file1); book.save(file2)`. What is the solution?