# Can't write data into Excel-Sheet using openpyxl Workbook

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm trying to write to specific cells in a Excel-Sheet using openpyxl Workbook. At first I couldn't write to cells that already had data in them and now I can't write at all (or I'm just going crazy).

Here's my code:

```
    wb = load_workbook("..\\..\\Decision Tree Classifier  TPS\\Decision Tree Classifier  TPS\\TestData.xlsx")
    ws1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

    #this works
    print(ws1.cell(row=1, column=1).value)

    #these do not
    ws1['D3'] = 5
    ws1.cell(row=5, column=1).value = "SomeValue2"
    ws1.cell(row=7, column=1,value='Hey')
    ws1.cell(row=6, column=1).value = 'TEST'

    wb.save("TestData.xlsx")
```

I get no errors, the print line works, the write lines do not.

Similar problem here [Writing data into Excel-Sheet using openpyxl isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29901558/11580452), except I have the save function.

What gives?

Comment: What do you mean by "do not work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're saving workbook, provide full path, otherwise you will save it in a Python folder. I'm pretty sure that's where your Excel workbook with new data resides.

```
wb.save("..\\..\\Decision Tree Classifier  TPS\\Decision Tree Classifier  TPS\\TestData.xlsx")
```

Also, don't forget to close your workbook when you're done with it.

```
wb.close()
```

Hope this helps!